# Asking a question about Emacs editor

Tags: support, asking-questions

I have a question regarding Emacs editor.

Should I post it on StackOverflow with tag **emacs**, post it in [Emacs beta](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/) or both?

Comment: Is it about the editor, or is it a programming question?

Comment: It is about deriving from c-mode for a small change of functionality (I still don't know if that implies a small code change or if it is possible), so I guess is both.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely don't do both, crossposting is always a bad idea. I imagine the overlap of people who answer on the beta site and who answer in that tag on SO is quite high, anyway.

It depends on the exact nature of your question. If it's more configuration related than programming it probably would be better on the beta site, but read https://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic first.